# finding a point of intersection

Tags: analytic-geometry

I need to find a point on the $y-axis$ so the tangents from that point to circles:

$(x-6)^2+(y-3)^2=16$, $(x-4)^2+(y-6)^2=5$ are equal in length.

I tried to use $(x-a)(x_1-a)+(y-b)(y_1-b)$ but it was quite messy.
i also tried to use $(-ma+b-n)^2=R^2(m^2+1)$ but couldn't see the end of it.
i tried to use distances some how but it was too complex in the calculation part.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean equal in length?

Comment: yes i do, thanks.

Comment: As you mean "equal in length", please edit the body of your question accordingly. People shouldn't have to go through the comments to understand the question.

Comment: Never mind, I did it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is useful to make a sketch of the two circles. Let the point we are looking for be $P=(0,b)$.

By the Pythagorean Theorem, the square of the distance from $P$ to the points of tangency to the first circle is given by
$$\left((0-3)^2+(b-6)^2\right) -16.$$
You can write a similar expression for the square of the distance from $P$ to the points of tangency with the second circle.

Equate the two squares of distance, and solve for $b$.